# Can anyone spot why this mysql_query isn't insert into DB

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my code so far...

```
if (isset($_POST['projectName']))
{

    $projectName = $_POST['projectName'];
    $dueDate = $_POST['dueDate'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $requestor = $_POST['requestor'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    //Update into the DB
    $updateSQL = mysql_query("INSERT INTO projects 
                                (projectName, 
                                dueDate, 
                                description, 
                                requestor,
                                status
                                )
                                VALUES 
                                ('".$projectName."','
                                ".$dueDate."','
                                ".$description."','
                                ".$requestor."','
                                ".$status."')");


    /*
    header('Location:manage.php?update=insertSuccess');
    exit();
    */  

}
```

Every value is getting inserted into the DB successfully except for $status. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The rampant [sql injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com) would suggest one reason why... enjoy having your server pwn3d. The lack of any error checking is another reason - assuming your query succeeded is not a good way of going about things.

Comment: What does mysql_error() say?

Comment: `mysql` is oooold ... blahblah, read http://php.net/mysql-connect

Comment: Sounds like the status field is not successfully posting from the form. Show some of your HTML form code, specifically the status field.

Comment: @MarcB- although you have pointed out issues with the code, none of this, as you state, could possibly be the reason for his code not doing as expected.

Comment: @Lock - What you are saying would be correct if Marc had not put this in a comment and had used it as an answer...

Comment: @Buggabill- correct, although he used terms such as "would suggest one reason why" and "The lack of any error checking is another reason" which suggests these are the reasons he is not getting an expected action

Comment: @Lock Actually, it is possible that data isn't getting into status because of SQL injection. What if a user puts in `') --` for status? That would close the insert and make the rest of the line a comment. However, is nobody curious about the data types of the table? I have $2 on it being an INT instead of VARCHAR or something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax looks fine but...

- You're not catching errors so it's probably some sort of column constraint.

> ```
> $updateSQL = mysql_query("INSERT...") or die(mysql_error());
> ```

Will catch these errors.

- While you're at it, you need to stop using `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Here's something to get you started:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (!$link) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO projects (projectName, dueDate, description, requestor, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssss', $projectName, $dueDate, $description, $requestor, $status);

/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));

/* close statement and connection */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```